# Optimizing a jtable

Tags: java, swing, paint, graphics2d, tablecellrenderer

I've created a `TableCellRenderer` out of a `JLabel` whose `paint()` is somewhat heavy, mostly bacause of a `g2d.drawString()` which is given a utf string. The problem is that this `paint()` is very repeatedly called, within the following stack:

```
MultiTableCellRenderer$TableHeaderLabel.paint:235   
CellRendererPane.paintComponent:151 
BasicTableUI.paintCell:2115 
BasicTableUI.paintCells:2016    
BasicTableUI.paint:1812 
ComponentUI.update:161  
JComponent.paintComponent:780   
JComponent.paint:1056   
JComponent.paintChildren:889    
JComponent.paint:1065   
JViewport.paint:728 
JComponent.paintChildren:889    
JComponent.paint:1065   
JComponent.paintChildren:889    
JComponent.paint:1065   
JComponent.paintChildren:889    
JComponent.paint:1065   
JComponent.paintChildren:889    
JSplitPane.paintChildren:1047   
JComponent.paint:1065   
JComponent.paintToOffscreen:5219    
RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered:1572    
RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint:1495  
RepaintManager.paint:1265   
JComponent._paintImmediately:5167   
JComponent.paintImmediately:4978    
RepaintManager$4.run:824    
RepaintManager$4.run:807    
AccessController.doPrivileged   
....
```

How can this repeating process be prevented? I've checked the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` implementation, and saw that they have overriden many of the methods, such as `repaint()`, `revalidate()` etc. replacing most of them with empty methods to enhance performance. I also did so, and it did help, but yet the greater part of the problem is staying there. At least about 10% of my CPU is constantly consumed by this very `paint()` method, and the entire application has been seriously slowed down. Any idea?

Comment: Code would help. Why do you override the renderer's paint method? Note that it is rarely recommended to override paint, but rather to override paintComponent, although this will not likely help your problem. Could your display be solved without either override? Please tell and show us more.

Comment: Best if you could create and post your [mcve], a minimal runnable program that shows us your problem directly. This is not a full code dump, and should not be posted to a link. Please read the link above for more on this.

Comment: *"..is somewhat heavy.."*  Do you mean that the app. visibly slows down, or that a profiling tool indicates that is a bottleneck in the app.?

Comment: TableCellRenderer is called from all mouse, key, models and listeners events and methods implemented in rellated APIs, everything described in your question could be standard output, rest are in previous comments above ...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, it is **visibly** slowing down and not negligibly. Profiling also indicated that the paint() is in charge of the CPU usage. I checked the time consumed by the method and 80% of its time, about 2ms on average, was due to the drawString() as I said.

Comment: `replacing most of them with empty methods to enhance performance. I also did so, and it did help,` Why don't you just extend the default renderer instead of trying to mimic what the default renderer does. You can still override the paint() method. Although custom painting should be done by overriding the paintComponent() method, not paint().

Comment: @camickr For no good reason, actually! I'm utilizing no single feature of a JLabel, not even super.paint(). To be honest, the mere reason is that I have written its base code serveral years ago, when I knew not much of Java! ...

Comment: @mKorbel but the method is being called even when the app is minimized! I can't see what events might have caused the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why the paint method is invoked excessively, you can start by checking [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) JavaDoc.
You also need to understand Swing drawing mechanism and how revalidation works.
You can read about Painting in AWT and Swing [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

A simple and efficient (performance-wise & code-wise) rule of thumb, is to extend DefaultTableCellRenderer and customize it to your needs.
Customization is usually done by overriding `setValue()` or `getTableCellRendererComponent()`.

It's important to note that `getTableCellRendererComponent()`:

1. Usually returns a reference to itself.
2. Should **not** create a new object each time it is called exactly for performance reasons.
3. Acts as a rubber-stamp for rendering **all** cells, one at a time.
4. Uses an optimized Object (Modified `JLabel` in the case of DefaultTableCellRenderer) for drawing, revalidation and repainting.

Try comparing your existing implementation and this implementation using the profiler to convince yourself that it produces much less drawing and layout events as well as a better CPU utilization.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but actually what I need is to customize the `paint()`...